# Using User Inputs

Tags: input, java.util.scanner

I cant seem to get this to come back with a result it always crashes. I know how to stop it from crashing just haven't gotten around to it. Eclipse Tells me the userIn is never closed. If you could tell me where I went wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Translator {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Word?");

        String word;

        word = userIn.nextLine();

        if(word == "Pollo"){

            System.out.print("Pollo - Chicken");

        }if(word == "Bien"){

            System.out.print("Bien - Good");

        }if(word == "Alto"){

            System.out.print("Alto - Tall");

        }

    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `word.equals("Pollo")` instead of `word=="Pollo"`. This is the same with the rest of them. This is because you want to compare the word not the objects.

Example : `if(word == "Pollo")` change to `if(word.equals("Pollo"))`

Comment: *you are currently comparing the objects and not the word